# Fiddler 2 error: SecureClientPipeDirect failed: System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: fiddler

I am trying to decrypt the https traffic by fiddler2 which has just been upgraded.
What is the problem to get this errror?

17:27:45:6821 !SecureClientPipeDirect failed: System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. < A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond on pipe to (CN=192.168.0.100, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the client failed to complete the HTTPS handshake. What was the client? This message typically indicates that the client isn't configured to trust Fiddler's Root Certificate.

What, if any, other messages are shown on the **Log** tab?